# Python: Split CSV with character count

Tags: python, csv, input

Need help in importing CSV file into python.

My CSV file

```
0,Donc, 2 jours, je me suis rendu compte que Musikfest est le lendemain de voir dmb, quel problème. Signifie que je ne peux pas aller ...
0,Le son est définitivement gâché.Noooooo mon bb
0,Il est le mien! Haha il me suit: ') m'aime et me veut.haha.i wana vivre en Amérique annie
```

I want to split the above file into 2 columns

```
Coloumn1 ---- Coloumn2
 0 ---- Donc, 2 jours, je me suis rendu compte que Musikfest est le 
        lendemain de voir dmb, quel problème. Signifie que je ne peux pas 
        aller ...
 0 ---- Le son est définitivement gâché.Noooooo mon bb
 0 ---- Il est le mien! Haha il me suit: ') m'aime et me veut.haha.i wana 
        vivre en Amérique annie
```

Since my text has commas embedded and my value for the text is always the first character. Is it possible to read my CSV file with splitting first character and rest of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use csv library to work with csv files: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

```
import csv


result = []

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        result.append((row[0], ''.join(row[1:])))

print(result)
```

Comment: csv module is great, but it deals with csv files... The file shown by OP is **not** a CSV file!

Comment: @SergeBallesta why not? It may be treated as CSV because it has comma delimiters and also OP himself said **"My CSV file"** ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ You could also check out the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`string.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and specify a max split of 1. By this I mean, if you just want to split the line on the first comma, then do not read the file as a CSV. Instead read it line by line and split the line using `string.split(',', 1)`

Comment: Yeah, if the input file is not in csv format don't use the csv module but do custom parsing. +1